# Parse answer in Quora that contains code

Tags: python, selenium, text, html-parsing, quora

I want to parse this post from Quora or a generic post with code.
**Example**: http://qr.ae/Rkplrt

Through using Selenium, a Python library, I can get the HTML inside of the post:

```
 h = html2text.HTML2Text()
 content = ans.find_element_by_class_name('inline_editor_value')
 html_string = content.get_attribute('innerHTML')
 text = h.handle(html_string)
 print text
```

I would like it all to be a single chunk of text. But in the case of those tables that contain code, html2text inserts many `\n` and does not handle the indices of the rows.

So I can see this:
https://imageshack.com/i/paEKbzT4p (This is the principal div that contains the table with code.)
https://imageshack.com/i/hlIxFayop (The text that html2text extracts)
https://imageshack.com/i/hlHFBXvQp (Instead, this is the final print of the text, with problems with the index rows and extra `\n`s.)

I had already tried different settings, like bypasse_tables, present in this guide on github: (https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/blob/master/docs/usage.md#available-options), but had no success.

Could someone tell me how to use html2text in this case?

Comment: ... why didn't you include the images in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use `HTML2Text` at all.

`selenium` can get you the "text" directly:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://qr.ae/Rkplrt")

print(driver.find_element_by_class_name('inline_editor_content').text)
```

It prints the content of the post:

```
The single line of code must be useful, not something meant to be confusing or obfuscating.

...

What examples have you created or encountered ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `BeautifulSoup` (and I'm using `urllib` to communicate with the website because I'm not familiar with `selenium` but I'm sure it can be got to work) to do some simple parsing of the HTML:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# urllib opener
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
          urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
          urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
          urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0))

# Get page
html = opener.open("http://qr.ae/Rkplrt").read()

# Create BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

# Find the HTML element you want
answer = soup.find('div', { 'class' : 'ExpandedQText ExpandedAnswer' })

# Remove the stuff you don't want
answer.find('td', { 'class' : 'linenos' }).extract()
answer.find('div', { 'class' : 'ContentFooter AnswerFooter' }).extract()

# Print
print("\n".join(answer.stripped_strings))
```

I'm not entirely sure what you want to extract. The above gives you just the answer, including the code, without the line numbers:

```
This is:
#include <stdio.h>
int v,i,j,k,l,s,a[99];
main()
{
for(scanf("%d", &s);*a-s;v=a[j*=v]-a[i],k=i<s,j+=(v=j<s&&(!k&&!!printf(2+"\n\n%c"-(!l<<!j)," #Q"[l^v?(l^j)&1:2])&&++l||a[i]<s&&v&&v-i+j&&v+i-j))&&!(l%=s),v||(i==j?a[i+=k]=0:++a[i])>=s*k&&++a[--i]);
}
```

**Update:** OP asked for `<a>` and `<img>` tags to be replaced by their `href` and `src` values. The version of my script below should take care of this. It also handles multiple answers.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# urllib opener
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
          urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
          urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
          urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0))

# Get page
html = opener.open("https://www.quora.com/Is-it-too-late-for-an-X-year-old-to-learn-how-to-program").read()

# Create BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

# Place to store the final output
output = ''

# Find the HTML element you want
answers = soup.find_all('div', { 'class' : 'ExpandedQText ExpandedAnswer' })
for answer in answers:

  # Remove the stuff you don't want
  linenos = answer.find('td', { 'class' : 'linenos' })
  if linenos is not None:
    linenos.extract()
  answer.find('div', { 'class' : 'ContentFooter AnswerFooter' }).extract()

  # Replace <a> with its url
  for link in answer.select('a'):
    url = link['href']
    link.insert_after(url)
    link.extract()

  # Replace <a> with its url
  for img in answer.select('img'):
    url = img['src']
    img.insert_after(url)
    img.extract()

  # Attach to output
  output += "\n".join(answer.stripped_strings) + '\n\n'

# Print
print(output)
```

Comment: I do not know if could go BeautifulSoup always good, because the answers may contain links or tags with img src.

Comment: How would you like to parse those?

Comment: showing for <a> its href and for <img> its src tag .
But it must be also the text of the entire response .

Comment: I think you can probably do that with BeautifulSoup. Do you have an example page?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-too-late-for-an-X-year-old-to-learn-how-to-program
This is one with many answers .
I should scroll this page with Selenium .
The problem is that I do not know if BeautifulSoap is enlarged to manage all this content .

Comment: I updated my post. The new script does what you want, I think.